# Apache Camel - "Cannot acquire read lock"

Tags: apache-camel, idempotent

I'm using Apache Camel version 2.24.2.

I have two application servers that are polling a shared directory to pick up and process files. The files are small - only a few Kb.

I'm using the following in the route definition for this process:

```
file://${my.folder}?readLock=changed&readLockMinAge=${minAge}&inProgressRepository=#messageIdRepository&delay=${delay}&include=${include}
```

The files have to be a certain age (to ensure they've been fully written) and I'm using an idempotent repository to ensure each file is processed only once. I'm polling the directory every 10 seconds.

Whilst any file that gets put into the shared directory gets processed eventually, it's taking a lot longer than I would have expected to do so. Also, I am seeing lots of messages like this before the file is eventually processed:

```
Cannot acquire read lock within 20000 millis. Will skip the file: RemoteFile[myFile.xml]
```

The ".camelLock" file is then deleted from the shared directory before either of the two application servers secures a lock on the file (by creating another ".camelLock" file) and tries again.

Is my approach incorrect?

Comment: What is `#messageIdRepository`? You need something distributed across al nodes, like `InfinispanIdempotentRepository` or `HazelcastIdempotentRepository` to ensure idempotency in clustered environment.

Comment: @Bedla It's a JDBC repository which is located in a (shared) database.

Comment: Ok, is this idempotent repository created according the documentation with all required indexes? `When working with concurrent consumers it is crucial to create a unique constraint on the columns processorName and messageId.`

Comment: @Bedla Yes, that's correct. There's a unique index on PROCESSORNAME and MESSAGEID.